# Donor-management software

Tags: gratis, information-management, communication, contact-manager

I'm looking for software that a brand-new, very small nonprofit could use to **keep track of donors** (and potentially other kinds of supporters, like event attendees and email-list subscribers).

We have literally no money right now, so I'm looking for something open-source (or at least **free-as-in-beer**). We also don't need or want anything very complex; we're at the stage of asking friends and family right now, so our needs are really **basic**, but I'd like the organization to start following best practices from the beginning.

None of us are primarily development professionals *(development in the sense of fundraising)*, so the ideal program would be useful, and potentially scalable, but should **not have an especially steep learning curve**. We want the program to make us work smarter, not to be a net drain on our time.

Miscellaneous needs: Everyone at the organization has Macs, so native **OS X** support would be ideal. **Linux**-only solutions would also be ok, but Linux support is *not necessary*. A Windows-only program would be considered only if it was so good as to be worth setting up a virtual machine or dual-booting. If it is possible to work with the same list across multiple computers/users it would be a plus, but it is definitely *not* a requirement: only **one user** needs to work with the program regularly.

Comment: Would you consider using something simple like excel?  It really is a very powerful data tool for the average user.  You can create forms for data entry, it data analysis tools are decent...its the way I would go for a start up.

Comment: That's a useful thought … I'm going to look into making a database with LibreOffice. It requires me doing more of the work of figuring out what the workflow should be, but lacking a sensible purpose-specific program I think that may be the best route.

Comment: I'm missing the most important part of your requirements: **What do you want to do with that information** (now and in the future)? This will determine very much which (type of) software is applicable. Please [edit your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/7264/edit)

Answer (score 2):

[**CiviCRM**](https://civicrm.org/features) looks like it might satisfy most or all of your requirements:

- open-source: **Yes**
- free: **Yes**
- scalable: **Yes**
- easy learning curve: **?**
- cross platform (Mac/Linux/Windows): **Yes**
- track donors: **Yes**
- track event attendees: **Yes**
- mailing list for subscribers: **Yes**

As **James** suggests in the comments, it might be easiest to start with a simple spreadsheet or similar until an investment in something more complex is worthwhile.

A web based solution will likely incur a web hosting cost but this is a very inexpensive commodity item (**less than $50 per year**) and something which you may already be paying or plan to pay for if you have a website or plan to have a website.

A web based solution has advantages over a locally hosted application such as:

- you can access and update the information from anywhere (not just the office)
- online payments could be enabled to reduce administration costs
- administration only requires a web browser so this solution is platform independent
- can be integrated with social networking
- can be integrated with website

Comment: IIRC, You can also solicit donations using CiviCRM. Also, if you've got your non-profit paperwork, you can get free web hosting on Dreamhost

Answer (score 1):

Nation Builder has nice donor functions like lists and payments, email list functions and can build websites too. Not free though. Starts at $19 a month.

http://nationbuilder.com/

Comment: I don't think an organization asking for donations will accept to pay 19$/month.